# Error scrolling an image in Opencv

Tags: c, opencv

I began working with Opencv in Eclipse with c++, I have been trying to scroll a binary image but I have an error. A binary image only has one channel (1,0) or (0,255). In my `if` statement I have results with values like 1 or 254 and I want it to show me the pixel with a white value.

Here the code:

```
IplImage *img=cvLoadImage("/home/delfin/Imágenes/bw.JPG");
IplImage *gray;
IplImage *thresh;
int height=img->height; //altura de la imagen en píxeles
int width=img->width;   //anchura de la imagen en píxeles
int anchura_fila =img->widthStep; //calculamos el valor del paso
int i,j,etiqueta;
uchar* data=(uchar *) img->imageData; //cargamos los datos de la imagen en data
printf("Estamos procesando una imagen de %dx%d píxeles \n",width,height);

while(1)
{
    gray=cvCreateImage(cvSize(img->width,img->height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    thresh=cvCreateImage(cvSize(img->width,img->height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);

    cvCvtColor(img,gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    cvThreshold(gray,thresh,35,255,THRESH_BINARY);
    for(i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<width;j++)
        {
            if(data[i*anchura_fila+j]!=0) //Si el pixel no es negro
            {
                printf("El píxel %d %d tiene un valor de: %d    \n",j,i,data[i*anchura_fila+j]);
            }
        }
    }
    cvShowImage("original", img);
    char c = cvWaitKey(0);
    if(c == 27) break;
}
```

And here part of the results:

```
El píxel 523 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 524 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 525 520 tiene un valor de: 254 
El píxel 526 520 tiene un valor de: 254 
El píxel 527 520 tiene un valor de: 254 
El píxel 528 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 529 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 530 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 531 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 532 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 533 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 534 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 535 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 536 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 537 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 538 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 539 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 540 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 541 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 542 520 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 0 521 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 1 521 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 2 521 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 3 521 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 4 521 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 5 521 tiene un valor de: 255 
El píxel 264 521 tiene un valor de: 1 
El píxel 265 521 tiene un valor de: 1 
El píxel 266 521 tiene un valor de: 1 
El píxel 477 521 tiene un valor de: 255
```

Answer (score 1):

I think while you assume that BW.JPG is a binary image, JPEG compression has resulted in creating slightly different values closer to either 0 or 255. To test this, you can  save the images as a TIFF or BMP file with no compression after creating it, and then use it in your code.